# contacts.find doesn't work on Android 4 (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am working on an Android app (phonegap) that reads contacts from phones, It works fine on android 5 and above but when it comes to android 4 OS its not able to read the contacts from the phone so I want to ask if anyone has experienced this problem while working with contacts.find in phonegap.

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); //the onDeviceReady function takes place when the app starts

function onDeviceReady() {
// find all contacts displayName, Name and phoneNumbers
var fields       = ["displayName", "name", "phoneNumbers"];
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "";
options.multiple = true;
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
 var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "-"+(currentdate.getMonth()+1) 
    + "-" + currentdate.getFullYear() + "T" + currentdate.getHours() + ":" 
    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
 alert(datetime);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet?

Comment: Just posted it now

Answer (score 0):

I created sample for you and tested in android version 4.1.1, 4.2.2, 4.4.4 and its working perfectly fine.

Code is ::

firstly add the contact plugin 
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts`

and then write in index.html ::

```
<body>
    <h2>Contacts List</h2>
    <div id="mobile"></div>
    <div id="email"></div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
        function init() {
            navigator.contacts.find([navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName],gotContacts,errorHandler);
        }

        function errorHandler(e) {
            console.log("errorHandler: "+e);
        }

        function gotContacts(c) {
            console.log("gotContacts, number of results "+c.length);

            mobileDiv = document.querySelector("#mobile");
            emailDiv = document.querySelector("#email");

            /* Retriving phoneNumbers */
            for(var i=0, len=c.length; i<len; i++) {
                if(c[i].phoneNumbers && c[i].phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
                    mobileDiv.innerHTML += "<p>"+c[i].displayName+"<br/>"+c[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+"</p>";
                }
            }

            /* Retriving Email */
            for(var i=0, len=c.length; i<len; i++) {
                if(c[i].emails && c[i].emails.length > 0) {
                    emailDiv.innerHTML += "<p>"+c[i].emails[0].value+"</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok let me try yours and compare

Comment: I noticed that the useCapture in the  document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false); is set to false is there a particular reason?